# Parsing a twitter JSON

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I'm using the following code to perfom a search on Twitter's API :

```
$.post('lib/themattharris-tmhOAuth-38bd48b/search.php',
       {q:'@something',
       pages:'1'}
)
.done(function(xhr) {
    try 
    {
        var tweets = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        showError('Error : '+e.message);
        return;
    }
    if (tweets === null)
    {
        showError('Error : no tweets found');
        return;
    }

    $('#timeline').text(tweets.results[0].text);

})
.fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    showError('Error : ' + $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).error);
})
.always(function() {
    $('#load').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

But "tweets" is always `null`. My `search.php` does the search and simply echoes the result. I've checked the JSON returned in [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), no errors are found.

Any clues ?

**EDIT** here's `search.php` :

```
    require_once 'tmhOAuth.php';
    require_once 'tmhUtilities.php';
    require_once 'secrets.php';
    session_start();

    $tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
      'consumer_key'    => $consumerKey,
      'consumer_secret' => $consumerSecret,
      'user_token'      => $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'],
      'user_secret'     => $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret']
    ));

    $p['q'] = $_POST['q'];
    $p['pages'] = 1;
    $p['include_entities'] = 'true';

    $pages = intval($p['pages']);
    $results = array();

    $code = $tmhOAuth->request(
      'GET',
      'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
      $p,
      false
    );

    if ($code !== 200) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
        echo $tmhOAuth->response['response'];
        return;
    }     
    else
    {
        echo $tmhOAuth->response['response'];
    }
```

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but have you inspected the value of `xhr.repsonseText`?

Comment: I thought you were supposed to use .responseText

Comment: :-) garbage in, garbage out ;-)

Comment: Oh I know what was wrong : "The success callback function is passed the returned data, which will be an XML root element, text string, JavaScript file, or JSON object, depending on the MIME type of the response."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked ^^;

```
.done(function(myJson) {
    try 
    {
        var tweets = $.parseJSON(myJson);
    }
```

I thought you were supposed to use `.responseText` ?

**EDIT** : "The success callback function is passed the returned data, which will be an XML root element, text string, JavaScript file, or JSON object, **depending on the MIME type of the response.**"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the scope of `tweets`, i.e.

```
...
var tweets;

try{...}
catch{...}

if (tweets === null)
{
    // does this work now?
}

etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get tweets === null